# Possible to Change Jenkins URL? : http://localhost:8080

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Possible to Change Jenkins URL? : http://localhost:8080

1. Currently I have jenkins setup on a virtual machine.
2. Is it possible to setup Jenkins on a URL which is more is accessible for other users?
3. For example I dont want other users to access test results by connecting to the Virtual machine instead I want them to access a URL from their own device in turn enabling them to login and see test results via jenkins.

thanks for you help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say IP of your virtual machine is 192.168.x.x.

Open the Port 8080 via firewall and then change the URL of jenkins from 
"Manage Jenkins >>Config Sys >> Jenkins Location>" to "http://192.168.x.x:8080"

Now you can access it from other machine on same network domain.Just have to hit the url http://192.168.x.x:8080

You can now create different users with different privileges for the same.

You can find it under Manage Jenkins >> Manage Users >> Create Users.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to networking. The machines should be on the same network, so they can talk to each other (unless you have public IP).

The ONLY rule to give access is, `that machines can talk to each other` (of course, in their language, 0's & 1's).

I suggest following things to do to share the URL:

1. Ask the users to connect to the same network that your machine is in.
2. Verify whether they are able to PING your machine IP (get it from `ipconfig` command for windows -  router assigns IP for your machine, that starts with `192.168` or `10.10`). command example: `ping 10.10.1.10`
3. If any issues in Ping, it might be Windows Firewall or Anti-virus which might be blocking, so allow the IPs in your firewall so they can access your machine.
4. Then ask them to access Jenkins using the following URL `http://[IP of your machine:8080]`

Comment: I tried these steps all passed except i cannot access my http://[IP of your machine:8080] even on the same machine any other machines. They are in the same network and i am able to ping it as well. Also, i see this error on jenkins - It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.

Answer (score 0):

> We want the Jenkins web interface to be accessible from anywhere (not
> just on the local machine), so we’re going to open up the config file:
>
> `sudo nano /usr/local/opt/jenkins-lts/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist`
>
> Find this line:
>
> `<string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>`
>
> And change it to:
>
> `<string>--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0</string>`

RF : [Installing Jenkins on macOS](https://www.macminivault.com/installing-jenkins-on-macos/)